# Raycasting from player, hitting object and setting off custom event C++ UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, raycasting

I've been going in circles for a day now trying to get this going and I'm just getting nowhere. I'm trying to have multiple objects in the scene with individual animations and when I fire a raycast from my player and it hits one, have the UFunction(blueprintimplementableevent) go off on the object that it hits. Please help me this is absolutely stumping me.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use a `BlueprintNativeEvent`. This will allow you to create an `Implementation` function of the stuff you want to happen in C++, as well as a blueprint implementation, which can be different for each blueprint of that object type.

It is quite simple to use as well, for example, in your character's header file:

```
/** Called when the player presses the fire key */
UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent, Category = "Shooting")
void OnHit();
virtual void OnHit_Implementation();
```

And now your Cpp:

```
 void AMyGameCharacter::OnHit_Implementation()
 {
     UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("OnHit_Implementation!"));
     // Do whatever stuff you want to do in C++ here
 }
```

Now over in your character / actor blueprint, just go to the event graph, right click, and add the event of type `OnHit`. Make sure that you make a callback to the parent `OnHit` event though (right click on the event and hit "Add Call to Parent Function")

If you want an example of this you can look at the [C++ Battery Collector series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIptJ0YrYg0) or the [docs](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Blueprints,_Empower_Your_Entire_Team_With_BlueprintNativeEvents).